# How to compare X509 certificate object with another .pem extension certificate

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, pem

I have two .pem files(certificate and RSA private key) of a certificate. And I am fetching a `X509` openSSL certificate object from server. How should I compare this two certificate to make sure they are same or different?

Comment: To see the certificate in a human readable view:
`openssl x509 -in cert.pem -noout -text`
and compare them or save to a file and diff them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DER representation of the certificates should be the same. Either compare on binary level that they are the same (byte by byte or do SHA1 of each and compare hashes), or parse them and compare serial number, issuer and public key.

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this is to extract each PEM to text and comapre the texts:

```
$ openssl x509 -in a.crt -text -noout > a.crt.txt
$ openssl x509 -in b.crt -text -noout > b.crt.txt
$ diff a.crt.txt a.crt.txt
```

or, as a single command

```
$ diff <(openssl x509 -in a.crt -text -noout) <(openssl x509 -in b.crt -text -noout)
```

I found myself in the curious position of having two different PEM representations of the same certificate. Comparing PEMs failed but the above confirmed them to be the same.

Comment: "I found myself in the curious position of having two different PEM representations of the same certificate. " I've seen the same thing when using Keytool to import then export the certificate